# CDN vs FTP.. which is better

Tags: azure, cdn, web-development-server

I've been developing a site through microsoft azure. Been doing some styling with bootstrap and wanted to know if pulling the bootstrap library through CDN is faster or pulling it from my directory is faster after DEPLOYING? what will u suggest performance wise

Comment: I see it as, globally CDN is faster, in your own continent, does not matter much. If you host the file in your own CDN or FTP, the file wont disappear never (happened once).
If you work on localhost, then of course having the files in your own directory is faster, also you can work w/o internet connection.
I hope my ideas of that are helpful :)

Comment: The main issue here is not, if any individual request is faster or not, but using a CDN some browser may be able to use cached versions of the libraries requested and do an HTTP request to get them at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDN itself caches the files for specific timeperiod which makes it deliver the content faster. This adds an advantage when user first time visits your site. Also CDN have its geographical advantages. Also since the cache is shared between the users there will be minimal load on original server.I hope this would help you.